# MongoDB slow query using indexes

Tags: mongodb, bigdata, database-performance

I have MongoDB running in docker container using compose:

```
mongodb:
image: mongo:4
ports:
  - "27017:27017"
restart: always
command: --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=10
environment:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGODB_USER}
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGODB_USER_PASS}
volumes:
  - ${MONGODB_DATADIR}:/data/db
```

`MONGODB_DATADIR` locates to host machine directory, and it's an ordinary hard drive (not SSD). In my DB I have a collection with some documents. There are some stats:

```
{
    "ns" : "domains.domains",
    "size" : 5679596048.0,
    "count" : 38396115,
    "avgObjSize" : 147,
    "storageSize" : 1884860416.0,
    "capped" : false,
    "wiredTiger" : {
        ...
    },
    "nindexes" : 7,
    "totalIndexSize" : 2701312000.0,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 387567616,
        "URL_1" : 1452449792.0,
        "checkedBySEO_1" : 187138048,
        "checkedByUclassify_1" : 184221696,
        "is_alive_1" : 184528896,
        "SEO_in_batch_1" : 176033792,
        "uclassify_in_batch_1" : 129372160
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

As you can see I have several indexes in my collection. And all I want to do is to count documents by simple query using index. As such: `db.getCollection('domains').find({"checkedByUclassify":false}).count();`. And it takes more than 10 seconds to do. And MongoDB uses one processor for 100% and does not use memory that it able to use:
[image: MongoDB query top]

Considering that sum of all indexes is around 2.7Gb I don't understand why MongoDB can't just upload it to RAM if it's needed. Is it normal behavior for this situation and is there any ways to improve performance? Thanks.

Comment: I've heard MongoDB doesn't explicitly use RAM for caching anything, it only relies on the operating system to cache something for it. MongoDB only memory-maps files and keeps everything, including indices, on disk.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe so only way to improve performance is to move to SSD?

Comment: I'm a MongoDB newbie so don't take my words for granted, and I don't know if it's the only way, but it's certainly one way to improve performance. Note that Mongo lets you (although in a convoluted way) to keep the data on one drive and the index on the other, so you may move index to SSD without needing to also store the data on it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.